# Continuity of complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I want to show

> A map $\phi:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ by $z\mapsto\frac{z}{\text{Re} z}$ cannot be continuous on $\text{Re}z =0$.

The meaning of 'cannot be continuous' is that originally, the function is not defined on $\text{Re}z =0$ but can find some $z\in\Bbb C$ such that $\text{Re}z =0$ such that assigning some appropriate value in $\Bbb C$ to $f(z)$ makes the map $\phi$ still continuous?

My attempt is that for $z=it\in\Bbb C$ with $t\neq 0$, if we define some value $\phi(z)\in\Bbb C$, then writing $z = x+iy$, $\lim_{x\to 0, y= t}\frac{x+iy}{x}\to \infty$ so the limit does not exists. If $z = 0$ then $\lim_{x=y\to 0}\frac{x+iy}{x} = 1+i$ but $\lim_{x\to 0,y=0}\frac{x+iy}{x} = 1$. So the limit does not exists. Is my proof valid?

Comment: It looks fine to me (up to some nonstandard notation about double limits and directional limits)

Comment: @TitoEliatron What is a standard notation? could you edit the post?

Comment: Wait a minute.... I think you have to refine your proof.
Fix a point $z_0=i t_0$. So you have to show that $\lim_{z\to i t_0} \phi(z)$ do not exists.

For that, you can use these directionals limits (for example):
$$\lim_{\substack{x+iy\to it_0\\y=x+t_0}}\phi(z)\qquad\text{and}]\qquad \lim_{\substack{x+iy\to it_0\\y=-x+t_0}}\phi(z)$$

Comment: Yes. What I wrote above is $\lim_{x+iy\to it_0, y=t_0}\frac{x+iy}{x}$.

Comment: You have to preceed for all $t_0\in\Bbb R$ not only for $z=0$ (equivalently $t_0=0$).

Comment: Well I first assumed $t_0\neq 0$ and separate the case when $t_0= 0$ (following your notation). For $t_0\neq 0$ case the directional limit goes to infinity so the limit does not exists and for $t_0 =0$, I showed that two distinct directional limit has a different value showing the limit does not exist